# Django 1.4: PasswordInput and Placeholder on same CharField

Tags: django, django-forms

Django should create a CharField which is for password input and this also should be displayed on the CharField:

In HTML: `<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" value="">`

For a [password CharField](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/PasswordField) i use:

```
class AuthForm(forms.Form):
    username  = forms.CharField(label="Your Username" )
    pw = forms.CharField( widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False), label="Your Password" )
```

For a placeholder i would use:

```
pw = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
```

---

SOLUTION:

It seams that you don't need `(render_value=False)`, so the solution is:

```
forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
```

Comment: SO what is the question here?

Comment: no question anymore ;). unfortunately i can't answer to my own question.

Comment: I don't think so. I think you can answer your own question.

Comment: Can someone please copy & paste my solution so i can accept an answer so that the question will be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy-paste, according to request ;)

```
forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
```